# Webview not showing any content(html) react native

Tags: android, webview, react-native

Contents did showing up perfectly inside emulator and debug with real device but does not showing anything when testing out with real device *(using released .apk)*. It just only showed blank container with white color. Or do i missed something?

```
<WebView
     ref={(wView) => {this.wView = wView}}
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     // onBridgeMessage={this.onBridgeMessage}
     onMessage={this.onMessage}
     injectedJavaScript="window.postMessage = String(Object.hasOwnProperty).replace('hasOwnProperty', 'postMessage');"               
     automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
     domStorageEnabled={true}
     startInLoadingState={true}
     source={mainHtml} <-- load with, var mainHtml = require('./MainHtml.html');
     style={{width: 320,height:100,flex: 1}}/>
```

**Environment**

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.43.4
- react: 16.0.0-alpha.6
- Device(ASUS Zenfone)
- Android version 6.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've read [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/505) this is a known issue with Android when deploying in Release. The workaround is to point to the file with a `uri`:

```
{ uri: 'file:///pathto/file.html' }
```

Comment: So, mean it start from the project folder's root?

Comment: Thanks, got it working now.. what i did is, creating assets folder at `android\app\src\main\assets` and placed all the HTML files there and later on referencing it using `source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/<file-name>.html' }}`